# Getting zero and not the expected output in recursive factorial?

Tags: ruby

Not getting the expected output, only get 0 when I enter any value 5 or 6 or 7. I need to use ARGV to enter the value in the terminal. Need a single argument with a value 0 or higher. For testing Try 5 as an argument and get the expected output 120

```
def factorial(n)
  if n < 0
      puts "Wrong argument - need a single argument with a value 0 or more "
  else
      n * factorial(n-1)
  end
end

def main 
    puts factorial(ARGV[0].to_i)
  end                                                                     
main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions need a valid base case and a recursive case. Your base case returns the result of `puts`, which is `nil`. Thus, `factorial(5)` is `5 * factorial(4)`. Skipping a few steps, `factorial(1)` is `1 * factorial(0)`, which leads to `0 * factorial(-1)`. This will first display your error "Wrong argument"; then the program will try to evaluate `0 * nil`, and fail because multiplication with `nil` is not a thing.

The factorial needs to return `1` (without a recursive call) when `n` is `0`.

Comment: But you need to use ARGV

Comment: Your use of `ARGV` was correct, I did not think I need to comment on that. Your error is just missing the `elsif n == 0; 1` in `factorial`.

Comment: _"Your base case returns the result of puts"_ – `n < 0` handles invalid arguments. The base case is simply missing.

Comment: @Stefan: In absence of the correct base case, the `n < 0` case de facto becomes a new (and incorrect) base case (though the _intent_ is as you say, the code says otherwise).

Comment: If you say it that way it becomes much clearer. The sentence I quoted sounds (to me) as if the return value were wrong and needed to be fixed, like _"your base case returns the wrong value"_. Hence my comment.

Comment: @Stefan: I trust you, if you can think of a better phrasing feel free to edit it in.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to consider.. An accumulator in the parameters.

```
def factorial_aux(n, acc)

    if n < 1
        acc
    else
        factorial_aux(n - 1, acc * n)
    end

end

def factorial(n)

    #do some param checks here...

    factorial_aux(n, 1)

end

if __FILE__ == $0

    p factorial(10)

end
```